# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable -- Python map function

Tags: python

I am learning the `map` function right now. I am creating a function where we can add 2 in all the elements of a list and then print them in a terminal:

```
def add_twoineach(a):
    for i in a:
        i = i + 2
        print(i)
```

Till here it is all good.

I am trying to use `map` function to iterate through a list and add 2 to each of the element of a list:

```
y = list(map(add_twoineach, (1, 2, 3)))
```

but I am getting error:

```
    for i in a:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: `map` will call `add_twoineach` once for each element of the iterable that follows, `(1, 2, 3)` in this case, so it will call `add_twoineach(1)`, `add_twoineach(2)`, etc. - you need to make sure that the function that gets mapped to the iterable returns the result you want in the resulting iterable.

Comment: `add_twoineach` doesn't return anything. `y` will just be a list of `None`s.

Answer (score 0):

When using `map`, you do not need the for loop anymore as the `map` applies the function on your iteration

```py
def add_twoineach(a):
    i = a + 2
    return i

y = list(map(add_twoineach, (1, 2, 3)))
```

Answer (score 0):

It might help to think in terms of types. Python plays fast and loose with types, so let's have an example in a language that both is strict with its typing *and* uses `map` idiomatically -- Haskell.

The only bits of syntax that you might need to know is to read `::` as "has type of."

```hs
addTwo :: int -> int  -- takes an int and returns an int
addTwo x = x+2
-- this can also be written as addTwo = (+2), but don't worry about that

addTwoMany :: [int] -> [int] -- takes a list of ints and returns a list of ints
addTwoMany xs = map addTwo xs
```

as you can see, `map` takes a function that acts on a single value and instead acts on a whole list of values. This concept generalizes beyond lists to a group in Category Theory called "functors," where you take a function that acts on a single value and make it act on a group of those values instead.